# Idiomatic way to use Options in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, equals, tostring

I am converting some Java code to Scala, trying to make the code as idiomatic as possible.

So, I now have some code using Options instead of nullable values, and I wonder whether things are Scalaiish, or whether I'm wrong. So, could you guys please criticize the following snippet of code?

The areas in which I am specifically looking for feedback are:

- The use of a companion object as a factory, giving 2 options depending on whether we want to pass Options or Strings: is the String constructor fine, or should we always expose the fact that it is an Option?
- The use of preconditions: are there better ways to assert the fact that alpha3Code and name are mandatory, and a non-null option mustbe passed for alpha2Code? (I am resorting to [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for the string utils, as I haven't found anything in the Scala API)
- The implementation of hashCode, equals and toString. equals and toString delegate to Guava again, whereas equals uses pattern matching. Is there a more Scala-ish way?
- I know I could have used Case classes, which would have created default implementations, but I am mostly interested in learning how I should implement those for the cases where case classes cannot be used.

```
    package com.sirika.openplacesearch.api.language
    
    import com.google.common.base.Objects
    import com.google.common.base.Strings
    
    object Language {
        def apply(name : String, alpha3Code : String, alpha2Code : Option[String]) = new Language(name, alpha3Code, alpha2Code)
        def apply(name : String, alpha3Code : String, alpha2Code : String = null) = new Language(name, alpha3Code, Option(alpha2Code))
        def unapply(l : Language) = Some(l.name, l.alpha3Code, l.alpha2Code )
    }
    
    
    class Language(val name : String, val alpha3Code : String, val alpha2Code : Option[String]) {
        require(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(alpha3Code))
        require(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(name))
        require(alpha2Code != null)
        
        override def hashCode(): Int = Objects.hashCode(alpha3Code)
        
                override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
            case that: Language => this.alpha3Code == that.alpha3Code
            case _ => false
        }
    
        override def toString() : String = Objects.toStringHelper(this)
            .add("name", name)    
            .add("alpha3", alpha3Code)
            .add("alpha2", alpha2Code)
            .toString()
    }
```

Comment: The "trick" to using Options is to only use Options and force the consumer to do the same ;-) Of course this isn't always practical when dealing with Java (ick!). Welcome to SO.

Comment: I don't think require(alpha2Code != null) can ever fail since alpha2Code is an Option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should expose only `Option[String]` in factory method. For example I, as a user of your library, will also ask myself question which factory method I should use. And most probably I will use Option.

Scala gives us enough tools to make our lifes easier. For example you can use default for option like this:

```
def apply(name: String, alpha3Code: String, alpha2Code: Option[String] = None) = 
 new Language(name, alpha3Code, alpha2Code)
```

If I, again as user of your library, want to pass just string without wrapping it in `Some` each time, I can write my own implicit conversion like this:

```
implicit def anyToOption[T](t: T): Option[T] = Some(t)
```

or even (if I personally use nulls):

```
implicit def anyToOption[T](t: T): Option[T] = 
 if (t == null) None else Some(t)
```

But I believe, if you enforce option, it will make your API more solid and clear.

Comment: Actually, there is an easier way to wrap an object in `Option` such that a `null` value will become `None`: `Option(t)` (instead of `Some(t)`)

Answer (score 4):

You should avoid `null` unless there's a very good reason not to. As it is, you could have just written this:

```
def apply(name : String, alpha3Code : String, alpha2Code : String) = new Language(name, alpha3Code, Option(alpha2Code))
def apply(name : String, alpha3Code : String) = new Language(name, alpha3Code, None)
```

The preconditions are fine. You could write it like this:

```
require(Option(alpha3Code) exists (_.nonEmpty))
require(Option(name) exists (_.nonEmpty))
```

Not necessarily an improvement, though.

A `String` has `hashCode`, so I don't understand why you are calling another method to generate a hash code instead of just calling `alpha3Code.hashCode`. I do think there's something in the Scala API, though. Not sure.

The `equals` code should have a `canEqual` method, unless you make your class `sealed` or `final`. Pattern match is pretty much the way to do it, though you could have written it like this given the presence of an extractor:

```
case Language(_, `alpha3Code`, _) => true
```

But the way you wrote it is pretty much the way it is usually written.

Comment: The other answers seem to emphasize the fact that I should actually force the consumer to use the Option constructor. Do you agree with that statement ?

Comment: Regarding hashCode, it's true that in this case, I could directly use alpha3Code.hashCode, I didn't even think about it as I have the habit of always using guava syntax, which allows adding several keys : Objects.hashCode(alpha3Code, name)

Comment: And good point concerning the canEqual method. I was not aware of it. For others who do not know about the canEqual, you can refer to http://books.google.com/books?id=MFjNhTjeQKkC&pg=PA555&lpg=PA555&dq=scala+canEqual+method&source=bl&ots=FKukUGGNvo&sig=0rF3cRgwHVGZ22ggxX5j23nM32w&hl=en&ei=As1CTaWhMoPGlQfknZ35Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=scala%20canEqual%20method&f=false

Comment: Also: are the `` between alpha3Code intentional ? Do they mean "the value should match this.alpha3Code" ? I cannot find more information about that, so I would greatly appreciate a link.

Comment: In pattern matching, backticks mean to the compiler: "Pretend this value is capitalized".

Comment: @Sami Ok, lots of question. I agree that you should not have `null` as a valid input option, but there's no need to force the user to use `Option` on the factory if simple polymorphism will handle the problem. On the last topic, yes, the back ticks are intentional. See section 8.1.5 of the Scala Reference (http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

I dislike Options -- they add a level of indirection that's unnecessary and confusing in many cases. I dislike nulls even more, so I understand that often the use of Options is justified. However, you should always see if there is a more natural way to eliminate the the use of `Option` in an interface.

Default parameters or separate overloads are often a better option. So I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
package com.sirika.openplacesearch.api.language

import com.google.common.base.Strings
import com.google.common.base.Objects

object Language {
    def apply(name : String, alpha3Code : String, alpha2Code : String) = new Language(name, alpha3Code, alpha2Code)
    def apply(name : String, alpha3Code : String ) = new Language(name, alpha3Code)
    def unapply(l : Language) = Some(l.name, l.alpha3Code, l.alpha2Code )
}


class Language private (val name : String, val alpha3Code : String, val alpha2Code : Option[String]) {
    def this(name:String,alpha3Code: String ,alpha2Code:String) = this(name,alpha3Code,Option(alpha2Code))
    def this(name:String,alpha3Code: String) = this(name,alpha3Code,None)

    require(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(alpha3Code))
    require(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(name))

    override def hashCode  = alpha3Code.hashCode

    override def equals(other: Any) = other match {
        case that: Language => this.alpha3Code == that.alpha3Code
        case _ => false
    }

    override def toString = MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
        .add("name", name)    
        .add("alpha3", alpha3Code)
        .add("alpha2", alpha2Code)
        .toString()
}
```

[Guava docs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html)